# When to use different dependency injections techniques?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring Boot and i was trying to learn the differences between different dependency injection techniques.
Is there any scenario where dependency injection through field is always prefered over constructor or setter injection?
I read that field injection is always a bad practice.
If its bad then why we still do it?

Comment: Maybe this already answers your question: [Why field injection is evil](https://odrotbohm.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: there is no info about that.

**Long answer**:

It's strange that [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) don't even mention field injection in any way

> DI exists in two major variants, Constructor-based dependency
> injection and Setter-based dependency injection.

I haven't found any info about when field injection is preferred over two aforementioned ones, besides the time where you do not need any of the benefits of CBDI and SBDI(for example, easier testing and NPE avoidance) and you want to **keep your code short**, but even this argument becomes **obsolete** if you use Lombok. Why does this feature even exist in the first place, **IMHO**:

1.There was a **bad design choice** that lead to it's creation and use in production(Spring Framework's first version was published back in 2002 and probably there was no any debate about whether or not field injection is a bad practice at that time)

2.**Backward-compatibility** stopped from removing this feature because it could break already existing codebase.

Comment: In 2002 there was no such thing as field injection, there was only constructor or property y based injection. (No annotations back then).

Comment: @M.Deinum could you please explain why does this feature even exist? I cannot sleep without thinking about this matter anymore. You seem to have much more experience

Comment: For the design choices you would have to ask the framework developers, but the fact is that both CDI and the Resource injection from Java/JEE have the same features. It exists because well it is easy to do, which doesn't mean it is the right thing to do.